# Formatting Data to be a certain color

Tags: html, oracle, perl

So the output works perfect but what I need help on is when the SQL outputs the data and I would like the data to be a certain color based on states. This query will pull all the states that ARE NOT "PROD" 'NM','TERM','NULL','IDLE', 'YER'. The states that it will display in the table are "DOWN", "PM", and "MDS". Colors I would like for it to output are BLUE, YELLOW, RED. Can someone please help me with this? Thank you in advance! [image]

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST GET);
use CGI qw/:standard /;
use DBI;

$dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:ODBC:SMSDWDE2','admin','admin',{RaiseError =>1, AutoCommit=>1});
my $q = new CGI();
print $q->header;
print $q->start_html(-head=>meta({-http_equiv => 'X-UA-Compatible',
                       -content=>'IE=edge,chrome=1'}),

                       -style => {'src'=>'css/eq - Copy1.css'},
                                      {'src'=>'vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css'},
                                      {'src'=>'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'},
                                      {'src'=>'fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'},
                                      {'src'=>'vendor/animate/animate.css'},
                                      {'src'=>'vendor/select2/select2.min.css'},
                                      {'src'=>'css/util.css'},
                                      {'src'=>'css/main.css'},
                                      -script =>{'type'=>'text/javascript','src'=>'js/main.js'},
                                      {'type'=>'text/javascript','src'=>'vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'},
                                      {'type'=>'text/javascript','src'=>'vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js'},
                                      {'type'=>'text/javascript','src'=>'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'},
                                      {'type'=>'text/javascript','src'=>'vendor/select2/select2.min.js'},
                                      {'type'=>'text/javascript','src'=>'vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js'},

                                 -title=>'MET IN PHOTO');

print "             
<div id='wrapper'>
        <nav class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top' role='navigation'>
            <div class='navbar-header'>
                <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target=''.navbar-ex1-collapse'>
                    <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                </button>
                <a class='logo' href='#'>
                    <img src='images/ti-logo.png' alt='CoolAdmin' />
                </a>
                </div>
            <div class='collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse'>
                <ul id='active' class='nav navbar-nav side-nav'>

                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsMet.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> METROLOGY</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsCMPIMP.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> CMP/IMP</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsDIFFWET.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> DIFF/WET</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsPHOTO.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> PHOTO</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsPLASMA.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> PLASMA</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsTHINFILM.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> THINFILM</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-user'>
                    <li class='divider-vertical'></li>
                    <li>
                        <form class='navbar-search'>
                            <input type='text' placeholder='Search' class='form-control'>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id='page-wrapper'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-lg-12'>
                    <h1>Critical Dashboard <small>Metrology</small></h1>

                </div>
                </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-lg-12'>
                    <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                        <div class='panel-heading'>
                            <h3 class='panel-title'><i class='fa fa-bar-chart-o'></i> Fab Dashboard - DMOS5 </h3>
                        </div>
                        <table class='table'>
                            <thead>

                            <tr>

                                    <th>MISTI</th>
                                    <th>STATE</th>
                                    <th>HRS</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                    </div>";

$sqlstr="Select 
       g.entity as MISTI,
       t.cur_state      as STATE,
       ROUND(((SYSDATE-t.cur_state_dttm)*24),2) AS HRS

From Entity_Grp_Lst g
left outer join trk_id_def t
on g.facility = t.facility
and g.grp_type = t.grp_type
and g.entity=t.entity
and g.grp_type = '720'
WHERE t.cur_state NOT IN ('PROD','NM','TERM','NULL','IDLE', 'YER')
and Entity_Grp_type = '041'
and g.ENTITY_GRP in ('MET')
-- add and g.entity in ('WSI04') to list all tools

AND ROUND(((SYSDATE-t.cur_state_dttm)*24),2) > 48  
order by t.cur_state_DTTM desc

";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlstr);
$sth->execute();
$sth->bind_columns(undef, \$MISTI, \$STATE, \$HRS);
while($sth->fetch()) {

   print "

                            <tbody>
                                <tr class='row100 body'>
                                    <td class='cell100 column1'><FORM ACTION='http://d5lxgenwebapp01z.dal.make.ti.com/get_de1_de2_misti_comments.pl' METHOD='POST' target='_blank' NAME='userInput2'>
        <INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='eq' MAXLENGTH='8' VALUE='$MISTI'>
              <INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='pages' SIZE='3' MAXLENGTH='2' VALUE='50'>
        <INPUT TYPE='submit' NAME='submit' VALUE='$MISTI'></form></td>
                                    <td class='cell100 column2'>$STATE</td>
                                    <td class='cell100 column3'>$HRS</td>

                                </tr>

   </tr>";
}

print "</tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();

print "


</body></html>";
```

Comment: You mean `<td class='cell100 column2 $STATE'>$STATE</td>` and a css of `.DOWN { color : blue } .PM { color: yellow } .MDS { color: red }`

Comment: Why not just make a [mcve] using HTML and CSS? Is there any need for us to see the perl and other server stuff?

Comment: Also your HTML is invalid. You have loose `</div>`s and `</tr>`s flowing around and a quote and a dot too many in `data-target=''.navbar-ex1-collapse'>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reuse the values as class names

`<td class='cell100 column2 $STATE'>$STATE</td>`

I have fixed a few illegal HTML elements too

```css
.DOWN {
  color: blue
}

.PM {
  color: yellow
}

.MDS {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div id='page-wrapper'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-lg-12'>
      <h1>Critical Dashboard <small>Metrology</small></h1>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-lg-12'>
      <div class='panel panel-primary'>
        <div class='panel-heading'>
          <h3 class='panel-title'><i class='fa fa-bar-chart-o'></i> Fab Dashboard - DMOS5 </h3>
        </div>
        <table class='table'>
          <thead>

            <tr>

              <th>MISTI</th>
              <th>STATE</th>
              <th>HRS</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr class='row100 body'>
              <td class='cell100 column1'>
                <form ACTION='http://d5lxgenwebapp01z.dal.make.ti.com/get_de1_de2_misti_comments.pl' METHOD='POST' target='_blank' NAME='userInput2'>
                  <INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='eq' MAXLENGTH='8' VALUE='$MISTI' />
                  <INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='pages' SIZE='3' MAXLENGTH='2' VALUE='50' />
                  <INPUT TYPE='submit' NAME='submit' VALUE='$MISTI' />
                </form>
              </td>
              <td class='cell100 column2 DOWN'>DOWN</td>
              <td class='cell100 column3'>$HRS</td>

            </tr>
            <tr class='row100 body'>
              <td class='cell100 column1'>
                <form ACTION='http://d5lxgenwebapp01z.dal.make.ti.com/get_de1_de2_misti_comments.pl' METHOD='POST' target='_blank' NAME='userInput2'>
                  <INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='eq' MAXLENGTH='8' VALUE='$MISTI' />
                  <INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='pages' SIZE='3' MAXLENGTH='2' VALUE='50' />
                  <INPUT TYPE='submit' NAME='submit' VALUE='$MISTI' />
                </form>
              </td>
              <td class='cell100 column2 PM'>PM</td>
              <td class='cell100 column3'>$HRS</td>

            </tr>
            <tr class='row100 body'>
              <td class='cell100 column1'>
                <form ACTION='http://d5lxgenwebapp01z.dal.make.ti.com/get_de1_de2_misti_comments.pl' METHOD='POST' target='_blank' NAME='userInput2'>
                  <INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='eq' MAXLENGTH='8' VALUE='$MISTI' />
                  <INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='pages' SIZE='3' MAXLENGTH='2' VALUE='50' />
                  <INPUT TYPE='submit' NAME='submit' VALUE='$MISTI' />
                </form>
              </td>
              <td class='cell100 column2 MDS'>MDS</td>
              <td class='cell100 column3'>$HRS</td>

            </tr>



          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When the SQL runs it populates the table so there will be multiple rows which you can't tell which states will be on what row. I uploaded a picture above.

Comment: You dont need to -  just add it as a class: `<td class='cell100 column2 $STATE'>$STATE</td> `

Answer (score 3):

There are a few improvements that you can make to this code.

- Always have `use strict` and `use warnings` in your code. And fix the problems they reveal (mostly declaring variables with `my` by the looks of it).
- You have `use CGI /:standard/` which imports a load of CGI's functions into your namespace, but then you only call those functions as methods on your CGI object (in `$q`) so that import is unnecessary.
- You use indirect object notation (`new CGI`) to create your CGI object. This will work 99% of the time but in the rare cases when it breaks you will waste days tracking down the problem. Far better to use `CGI->new` instead.
- The HTML creation functions in CGI.pm (you use `start_html()`) have been [deprecated for some time now](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used). Please don't use them.
- Having raw HTML in your Perl code is likely to be a maintenance problem (as you seem to have discovered, given the errors in your HTML). I strongly recommend moving your HTML out of your Perl code and into templates. [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) has some suggestions on ways to do this.