# HTML/SQL table formatting

Tags: html, sql, perl

I have this SQL query that pulls all the data I need and it formats it the way I like but I am missing one column which that data is not in the DB. Depending on what the data outputs I would like to group the results in a certain bucket(Column 1). The Query I have pulls all the MIST, STATES, and HRS greater than 48HRS. How can I have the output data link to its corresponding group? Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Excel Example of what I am trying to do.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
print "             
<div id='wrapper'>
        <nav class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top' role='navigation'>
            <div class='navbar-header'>
                <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target=''.navbar-ex1-collapse'>
                    <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                </button>
                <a class='logo' href='#'>
                    <img src='images/ti-logo.png' alt='CoolAdmin' />
                </a>
                </div>
            <div class='collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse'>
                <ul id='active' class='nav navbar-nav side-nav'>

                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsMet.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> METROLOGY</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsCMPIMP.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> CMP/IMP</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsDIFFWET.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> DIFF/WET</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsPHOTO.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> PHOTO</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsPLASMA.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> PLASMA</a></li>
                    <li><a href='CriticalToolsTHINFILM.html'><i class='fa fa-globe'></i> THINFILM</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-user'>
                    <li class='divider-vertical'></li>
                    <li>
                        <form class='navbar-search'>
                            <input type='text' placeholder='Search' class='form-control'>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id='page-wrapper'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-lg-12'>
                    <h1>Critical Dashboard <small>THINFILM</small></h1>

                </div>
                </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-lg-12'>
                    <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                        <div class='panel-heading'>
                            <h3 class='panel-title'><i class='fa fa-bar-chart-o'></i> Fab Dashboard - DMOS5 </h3>
                        </div>
                        <table class='table'>
                            <thead>

                            <tr>
                                    <th>TOOLGROUP</th>
                                    <th>MISTI</th>
                                    <th>STATE</th>
                                    <th>HRS</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                    </div>";

$sqlstr="Select 
       g.entity as MISTI,
       t.cur_state      as STATE,
       ROUND(((SYSDATE-t.cur_state_dttm)*24),2) AS HRS

From Entity_Grp_Lst g
left outer join trk_id_def t
on g.facility = t.facility
and g.grp_type = t.grp_type
and g.entity=t.entity
and g.grp_type = '720'
WHERE t.cur_state NOT IN ('PROD','NM','TERM','NULL','IDLE', 'YER', 'I05', 'I07')
and Entity_Grp_type = '041'
and g.ENTITY_GRP in ('THINFILM')
and (g.entity like 'CV403%' or
g.entity like 'CV406%' or
g.entity like 'CV405%' or
g.entity like 'CV132%' or
g.entity like 'MT105%' or
g.entity like 'MT106%' or
g.entity like 'MT117%' or
g.entity like 'MT118%' or
g.entity like 'MTA08%' or
g.entity like 'MTA13%'  )



AND ROUND(((SYSDATE-t.cur_state_dttm)*24),2) > 48  
order by t.cur_state_DTTM desc

";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlstr);
$sth->execute();
$sth->bind_columns(undef, \$TOOL_GROUP, \$MISTI, \$STATE, \$HRS);
my %tool_groups = (
  CV403 => 'ARC_SOUTH',
  CV405 => 'ARC_SOUTH',
  CV406 => 'ARC_SOUTH',
  CV132 => 'BPSG',
  MT105 => 'COBALT',
  MT106 => 'COBALT'
);
while($sth->fetch()) {
    while($sth->fetch()) {
    my $TOOL_GROUP;
if (exists $tool_groups{$MISTI}) {
  $TOOL_GROUP = $tool_groups{$MISTI};
} else {
  warn "Unknown tool group for MIST: $MISTI";
  next;
}

   print "

                            <tbody>
                                <tr class='row100 body'>
                                 <td class='cell100 column3'>$TOOL_GROUP</td>
                                    <td class='cell100 column1'><FORM ACTION='http://d5lxgenwebapp01z.dal.make.ti.com/get_de1_de2_misti_comments.pl' METHOD='POST' target='_blank' NAME='userInput2'>
        <INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='eq' MAXLENGTH='8' VALUE='$MISTI'>
              <INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='pages' SIZE='3' MAXLENGTH='2' VALUE='50'>
        <INPUT TYPE='submit' NAME='submit' VALUE='$MISTI'></form></td>
                                    <td class='cell100 column2 $STATE'>$STATE</td>
                                    <td class='cell100 column3'>$HRS</td>

                                </tr>

   </tr>";
}

print "</tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <p >Email: <a href='mailto:?subject=CRITICAL TOOLS DASHBOARD WEBPAGE'>Ru
                                Med</a></p>
                </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();

print "


</body></html>";
```

Comment: You're going to have to explain the rules for how you "would like to group the results in a certain bucket". Without more details, it's hard to see how we can be much help (well, other than repeating [the suggestions from your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56855003/7231)).

Comment: Hi @Dave so if the sql query outputs CV403 I would like the first column to be labeled ARC_SOUTH or if it outputs MTA13 I would like the first column to display COBALT. Sorry if I was a little confusing when trying to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

It's still not very clear, but I think the solution to this is a simple hash. If you have this in your code:

```
my %tool_groups = (
  CV403 => 'ARC_SOUTH',
  CV405 => 'ARC_SOUTH',
  CV406 => 'ARC_SOUTH',
  CV132 => 'BPSG',
  MT105 => 'COBALT',
  MT106 => 'COBALT',
  # etc...
);
```

Then in your loop, you can do this:

```
my $tool_group;
if (exists $tool_groups{$MISTI}) {
  $tool_group = $tool_groups{$MISTI};
} else {
  warn "Unknown tool group for MIST: $MISTI";
  next;
}
```

And then use `$tool_group` in your output.

But **please** take note of [the advice I gave you in response to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56855003/7231). You are making your life far harder than it needs to be.

**Update:** But honestly, I think that information like this should be in a database table. Just add a table that contains the Mist to Tool Group mapping and then you can get the data by just adding a join to your SQL.

Comment: Sorry still all new to this but where exactly would I place this loop? I have looked at your recommendations from the last post and I am currently in the process of redoing this application but everything is still a learning process for me so I am taking it all step by step.

Comment: @Dc5nipe: You don't need to place the loop anywhere. You already have a loop - your `while` loop which iterates over the results pulled back from the database. You put the hash initialisation outside of this loop and the bit that sets `$tool_group` inside your `while` loop, before the `print()` statement. You can then add something like `<td>$tool_group</td>` to the `print()` statement.

Comment: So I made the recommended changes to my original postbut it didn't pull any data. Can you point me to where I messed up at? Thank you!

Comment: I know you probably been very busy but whenever you get a chance can you overlook the code above? This is the last step to this project. Thank you!

Comment: @Dc5nipe You still (correctly, I believe) only pull three columns from the database. So I'm not sure why you've added an `undef` and `$TOOL_GROUP` to your call to `bind_params()` (you haven't even declared `$TOOL_GROUP` at that point). If you reset your call to `bind_params()` to how it originally was, then I think it'll work.